# How to implement Google Auth in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, google-authentication

How to implement Google Auth in Xamarin. Forms.Online sources are not that much useful...I've tried with Houssaim Dellai plugin.But it is not supported in .net core v4.6. I cant find the Model and View Pages.Please do help me.

Comment: You should be more specific and provide some code that you have tried so far. Otherwise it seems that you are simply looking for a tutorial that in turn is not welcomed here at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried Xamarin.Auth (github: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth)?

Take a look at "Authenticating Users with an Identity Provider" 
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/oauth)